# Selecting row that was dragged and dropped in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, drag-and-drop, selectedindex

I created a datagridview with some sample data. When I drag a row in the datagridview to another position this works fine. The only thing I can't get working after hours of attempts is to get the row highlighted that was dragged.
In my code the row gets highlighted where the row was originally.

Below some screenshots:
[image: before]
[image: after]

As you can see I moved row 8 to row 14 but row instead of highlighting row 14 it stays on row 8.

My code stripped:

```
        Private Sub DataGridViewForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            LoadDataGridView1()
        End Sub

        Public Sub LoadDataGridView1()
            ' Fill datasource
        End Sub

        Private Sub Dgv_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DatagridView1.DragDrop
           ' Code to move row up or down
        End Sub

        Private Sub Dgv_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DatagridView1.DragEnter
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End Sub

        Private Sub DataGridView_CellMouseDown(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DatagridView1.CellMouseDown
            Dim dname As DataGridView = sender
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                    Dim view As DataGridViewRow = DirectCast(dname.Rows(e.RowIndex), DataGridViewRow)
                    If view IsNot Nothing Then
                        dname.DoDragDrop(view, DragDropEffects.Copy)
                    End If
                    LoadDataGridView1()
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: Store the index of the dropped cell into a variable then set the highlighting using that index value.

Comment: is this a bound data source?

Comment: The LoadDataGridView1() is getting the data from an SQL table with a command like: $"SELECT * FROM {GV.DB}{MainDB} ORDER BY LISTORDER" so yes, it is a bound data source. I added an extra column LISTORDER to manipulate the order in which the rows are shown so you can drag and drop rows. But even when I insert a command like:

Comment: DataGridView1.Rows(10).Selected = True after the LoadDataGridView1() it will not highlight row 10, it will keep highlighting row 8 (the one from where the row was dragged)

Comment: Today I tried this:                 LoadDataGridView1()
                MsgBox("After load ")
                DatagridView1.ClearSelection()
                MsgBox("After clear ") and after I drag and drop the row I get the message "after load" and the first row is selected, then after click ok nothing is selected and the message comes up after clear, so that is working. After click ok on this message the row is selected that was last clicked. There must be some internal pointer that remembers which row was last selected and whatever you do, that is the one that will be selected afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it as follows for anyone interested:
In the CellMouseDown i set the colors:

```
  Private Sub Dgv_CellMouseDown(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DgvPersonen.CellMouseDown
    Dim dname As DataGridView = sender
    dname.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    dname.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Tomato
    dname.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = MyCustomColor
    dname.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Tomato
```

When it was a left mousebutton click on a row I select the row and save the color it was:

```
        dname.CurrentCell = dname(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
        OriginalColor = dname.Rows(OriginalRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
        dname.Rows(OriginalRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = OriginalColor
        dname.Rows(LastRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = OriginalColor
        Dim view As DataGridViewRow = DirectCast(dname.Rows(e.RowIndex), DataGridViewRow)
        If view IsNot Nothing Then
            dname.DoDragDrop(view, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        End If
```

OriginalRow and LastRow only get set when drag&drop rows as follows:

```
Private Sub Dgv_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DgvPersonen.DragDrop
    Dim dname As DataGridView = sender
    dname.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    dname.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Tomato
    dname.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = MyCustomColor
    dname.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Tomato

    Dim newRow As DataGridViewRow = dname.Rows(dname.HitTest(p.X, p.Y).RowIndex)
    If newRow.Index >= 0 And newRow.Index < dname.Rows.Count Then
        ' Get the dropped row info
        Dim oldRow As DataGridViewRow = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow)), DataGridViewRow)
        ' If the two rows aren't the same it inserts dropped row
        If newRow.Index <> oldRow.Index Then

            OriginalRow = oldRow.Index
            LastRow = newRow.Index
            OriginalColor = dname.Rows(OriginalRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
            FillDataGridViewsOnValue()
            dname.Rows(OriginalRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = OriginalColor
            dname.Rows(LastRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato
            dname.Rows(LastRow).Selected = True
            dname.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
            dname.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White
            dname.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = MyCustomColor
            dname.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = MyCustomColor
```

It was a lot of trial and error but it works now exactly like a want it to work.

Comment: Well, forget about that. The above solution was merely manipulating the colored rows. Not what is selected. I cancelled the drag & drop feature completely and moved to changing rows up and down with the shift + arrow keys.